# UINavigationController title and button

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UINavigationController` in which I push / display several other `UIViewControllers`. I would like a specific title and button (a Cancel button to be precise, which appears on the right-hand side) to always appear in the `UINavigationController`'s `UINavigationBar` regardless of the view controller being displayed within the navigation controller. At the moment I have set the `.title` and `.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` of each individual view controller to be the same, but this seems like (a) a lot of wasted effort; and (b) when a new view controller is pushed onto the stack there is a brief animation where the title and button can be seen animating out and then back in - obviously not desirable since I want to give the appearance that those items are static and never change.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set all you need in UINavigationController and then in viewWillAppear of your UIViewControllers subclasses paste:

```
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem];
```